# How to move an image when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the problem, that I want to create a page and there is one image over another and I want to make it go to different places on the second, larger image while you are scrolling.

So if you scroll down, the website should not go down, but on the second picture ( `id="maps"`
 the first picture  `id="train"` should move.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

    <head>
        <title>Vorstellung meiner Herausforderung</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src = "images/maps.png" alt = "Maps" id="maps">
        <img src="images/zug.png" alt= "Zug" id="train">
        <h1>Meine Herausforderung</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}

h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

#maps {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#train {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 55%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 3%;
}
```

Thanks for any help and sorry for my english.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Because I have no clou how to the thing with the scrolling and the 4 other Websites I went weren't helpful I tried it with css animatiions, but I don't know to do it with the scrolling.

Comment: Break it down: figure out how to listen for scrolling events, then figure out how to use `JavaScript` to grab a DOM element object, then figure out how to move an element using css, then figure out how to update that DOM's element styles/css so that it "moves" as you scroll. When you get stuck, come back here with what you have and we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be very happy to help you, if you provide more insight about the problem.

From the Problem statement I assume, you want to move a small image which is on top of a large image when you mouseover on it, without scrolling the body/window viewport.

Please check this helps you

```js
const $train = $('#train')
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
   $train.css({left: window.pageYOffset*10});
}, true /*Capture event*/);
```

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2
        overscroll: scroll;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #map-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/World_map_green.png);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    #map, .inner-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
    
    .inner-container { 
      background: transparent;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    #train {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        top: 20%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">

        <head>
            <title>Vorstellung meiner Herausforderung</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="map-container">
            <!-- <img src = "" id="maps"> -->
            <div class="inner-container">
             <img src="https://png2.cleanpng.com/sh/0f45ce863aeba0805894dc22bf651040/L0KzQYm3UsAzN5Dqj5H0aYP2gLBuTgRzaZpzRdVqcoTyf7A0kvFqdF55itN3c4DygsW0kvVlNaV3edt3LUXkR4WCWcdiQGpmfNcBLkC3RIq6UMg3OWY2T6cEMEmzRoa9U8kveJ9s/kisspng-train-cartoon-rail-transport-red-train-5a74997a89ade6.0449308615175909065639.png" alt= "Zug" id="train">
             </div>
  </div>
            <h1>Meine Herausforderung</h1>
            
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: First of all: Thank you!
The thing I really want to do is to move the train to predetermined points by scrolling down the website, but the map should not scroll down.
I don't know, my english isn't the best cause i'm a pupil from germany, sorry.

Comment: I'm still not clear with the requirement here. is it like when scrolling over the larger image small image should move ?

Comment: Yes, kind of...
If you scroll down on the page, than the small image should move on the big image.

Comment: is it possible for you to use large image as background-image ?

Comment: Yes, the only important thing is, that it should be a map of europe / the world